# TeamCity build "Process exited with code 99"

Tags: gruntjs, teamcity

I'm getting this error running a TeamCity build in a step that runs a grunt task.

> [Step 1/6] grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface (v1.2.0)
>
> [Step 1/6] Process exited with code 99

Any idea of what code 99 means?

Comment: This might help - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1459

Comment: that gave me and idea, thank you